# discontinue comma character in english language

Tags: punctuation, commas

comma character is represented by ,
can we create a new character in english language as discontinue which is trailing of comma character?

The use of discontinue character in the below sentence.

> Please do not cross the road as there is a red signal.

Between the word "road" and "as" add the discontinue character.

[image]

Comment: Is this helpful?  https://www.lexico.com/grammar/inverted-commas-quotation-marks

Comment: No, adding new characters is not permitted. Attempts to do so will result in immediate excommunication from the language.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Permanent banishment from the Anglophone sphere? Or can it be commuted by presidential order?

Comment: @EddieKal, what the President of English decrees, none may gainsay.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using an ordinary comma in "Please do not cross the road, as there is a red signal". There is no need to invent any new mark for this purpose.

Comment: @EddieKal Presidential order would do it, but with a president capable only of disorder, it's a long shot.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Let me find that mod tool that allows me to like a comment 10 times...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the jokes in the comments suggest, there is no person or organisation that decides what "English" is.  The rules of English are descriptions of how English is used by the millions of English speakers.

So if the question is "Can I start using a new punctuation mark" the answer is "yes", nobody will stop you.

If the question is "Will anybody else know what it means" the answer is "not unless you tell them"

If the question is "Will it become part of English" the answer is "You will have to convince millions of people that they need this character.  That seems very unlikely.

So the short answer is:  No you can't create a new character in English.